# SMTP server ready but 'Could not connect' error appears

Tags: smtp

I have set up a web server to use an SMTP server to send out emails.

Here is a section of the log entries generated when I try to send a test email:

```
2016-02-03 10:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2016-02-03 10:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
2016-02-03 10:20:01 Connection: closed
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT: Below is the complete log generated by the [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) plugin in WordPress. (I have replaced the real domains with example.com for privacy).

```
Test Message Sent

The result was:
bool(false)


The full debugging output is shown below:
object(PHPMailer)#752 (73) {
  ["Version"]=>
  string(6) "5.2.10"
  ["Priority"]=>
  int(3)
  ["CharSet"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["ContentType"]=>
  string(10) "text/plain"
  ["Encoding"]=>
  string(4) "8bit"
  ["ErrorInfo"]=>
  string(43) "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."
  ["From"]=>
  string(17) "sender@example.com"
  ["FromName"]=>
  string(14) "Administration"
  ["Sender"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ReturnPath"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Subject"]=>
  string(45) "WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to recipient@example.com"
  ["Body"]=>
  string(68) "This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin."
  ["AltBody"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Ical"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MIMEBody":protected]=>
  string(69) "This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin.
"
  ["MIMEHeader":protected]=>
  string(392) "Date: Wed, 3 Feb 2016 10:20:01 +0000
To: recipient@example.com
From: Administration 
Subject: WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to recipient@example.com
Message-ID: 
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.10 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

"
  ["mailHeader":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["WordWrap"]=>
  int(0)
  ["Mailer"]=>
  string(4) "smtp"
  ["Sendmail"]=>
  string(18) "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
  ["UseSendmailOptions"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PluginDir"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ConfirmReadingTo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Hostname"]=>
  string(14) "www.example.com"
  ["MessageID"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MessageDate"]=>
  string(30) "Wed, 3 Feb 2016 10:20:01 +0000"
  ["Host"]=>
  string(12) "192.168.1.23"
  ["Port"]=>
  string(2) "25"
  ["Helo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SMTPSecure"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SMTPAutoTLS"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["SMTPAuth"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["SMTPOptions"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Username"]=>
  string(9) "workflow"
  ["Password"]=>
  string(10) "example"
  ["AuthType"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Realm"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Workstation"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Timeout"]=>
  int(300)
  ["SMTPDebug"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["Debugoutput"]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  ["SMTPKeepAlive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleTo"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleToArray"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["do_verp"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["AllowEmpty"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["LE"]=>
  string(1) "
"
  ["DKIM_selector"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_identity"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_passphrase"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_domain"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_private"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["action_function"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["XMailer"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["smtp":protected]=>
  object(SMTP)#643 (13) {
    ["Version"]=>
    string(6) "5.2.10"
    ["SMTP_PORT"]=>
    int(25)
    ["CRLF"]=>
    string(2) "
"
    ["do_debug"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["Debugoutput"]=>
    string(4) "echo"
    ["do_verp"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["Timeout"]=>
    int(300)
    ["Timelimit"]=>
    int(300)
    ["smtp_conn":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["error":protected]=>
    array(4) {
      ["error"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["detail"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["smtp_code"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["smtp_code_ex"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["helo_rply":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["server_caps":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["last_reply":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["to":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(18) "recipient@example.com"
      [1]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["cc":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["bcc":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["ReplyTo":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["all_recipients":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["recipient@example.com"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["attachment":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["CustomHeader":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["lastMessageID":protected]=>
  string(49) ""
  ["message_type":protected]=>
  string(5) "plain"
  ["boundary":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(35) "b1_f87804706227482a31d3248b0776feb6"
    [2]=>
    string(35) "b2_f87804706227482a31d3248b0776feb6"
    [3]=>
    string(35) "b3_f87804706227482a31d3248b0776feb6"
  }
  ["language":protected]=>
  array(19) {
    ["authenticate"]=>
    string(35) "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate."
    ["connect_host"]=>
    string(43) "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."
    ["data_not_accepted"]=>
    string(30) "SMTP Error: data not accepted."
    ["empty_message"]=>
    string(18) "Message body empty"
    ["encoding"]=>
    string(18) "Unknown encoding: "
    ["execute"]=>
    string(19) "Could not execute: "
    ["file_access"]=>
    string(23) "Could not access file: "
    ["file_open"]=>
    string(33) "File Error: Could not open file: "
    ["from_failed"]=>
    string(35) "The following From address failed: "
    ["instantiate"]=>
    string(36) "Could not instantiate mail function."
    ["invalid_address"]=>
    string(15) "Invalid address"
    ["mailer_not_supported"]=>
    string(25) " mailer is not supported."
    ["provide_address"]=>
    string(54) "You must provide at least one recipient email address."
    ["recipients_failed"]=>
    string(45) "SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: "
    ["signing"]=>
    string(15) "Signing Error: "
    ["smtp_connect_failed"]=>
    string(22) "SMTP connect() failed."
    ["smtp_error"]=>
    string(19) "SMTP server error: "
    ["variable_set"]=>
    string(30) "Cannot set or reset variable: "
    ["extension_missing"]=>
    string(19) "Extension missing: "
  }
  ["error_count":protected]=>
  int(2)
  ["sign_cert_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_extracerts_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_pass":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["exceptions":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["uniqueid":protected]=>
  string(32) "f87804706227482a31d3248b0776feb6"
}


The SMTP debugging output is shown below:
2016-02-03 10:20:01 Connection: opening to 192.168.1.23:25, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2016-02-03 10:20:01 Connection: opened
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 3 Feb 2016 14:20:01 +0400
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 3 Feb 2016 14:20:01 +0400
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 3 Feb 2016 14:20:01 +0400
2016-02-03 10:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.example.com
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 10485760
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-DSN
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-AUTH
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-AUTH
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-AUTH
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-AUTH
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-BINARYMIME
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-AUTH
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-BINARYMIME
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-AUTH
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-BINARYMIME
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 CHUNKING
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-AUTH
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-BINARYMIME
                                      250 CHUNKING
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-AEADTWMAVSM002.example.com Hello [192.168.3.51]
                                      250-SIZE 10485760
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-DSN
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250-AUTH
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-BINARYMIME
                                      250 CHUNKING
2016-02-03 10:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
                                      "
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2016-02-03 10:20:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
2016-02-03 10:20:01 Connection: closed
2016-02-03 10:20:01 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Comment: You show us that you can connect to the server, but none of the details of the sending attempt, so it's hard to comment.  Is it possible the remote server requires `SMTP AUTH` in order to agree to relay your emails?  That would be fairly normal, these days.

Comment: Please the log on the other side. As in: What does the SMTP server say?How was this log generated? From the client app? It seems (unless I read it wrong) that it does connect (220 answer from the server) - so the server must have a reason to drop the connection.

Comment: @Enthusiast, lots of information are missing. You need to post the full log and not a section of it. Are you using phpmailer to send email?

Comment: ^ I've edited the question with the complete log that was generated by the WP Mail SMTP plugin in WordPress.

Comment: @Enthusiast, first of all, have a look here: http://www.callum-macdonald.com/code/wp-mail-smtp/. You will need to investigate more. Try to set Mailer in the plugin as SMTP and see. Also chek the authentication works, and try with or without ssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the WP Mail SMTP plugin, your best start point would be here: http://callum-macdonald.com/code/wp-mail-smtp. Now here is what the developer says:

> Could not connect to host
>
> If you see an error like “Failed to connect to server”, the plugin is
>   working, PHP cannot connect to the server. Look at the whole error
>   message and investigate from there. Check your php.ini settings around
>   fopen() permissions, check your SMTP host is correct, or contact your
>   server administrator.
>
> If your error is “Cannot connect to host”, please look for support
>   elsewhere, please do not ask for support here. These questions have
>   been asked many times before, please search the history. The plugin is
>   working, the issue lies elsewhere.

Since you haven't posted your settings for the plugin, and as it offers different configuration possiblities, here is some points to help you out.

- The debug error says: "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.", so check and make sure, your authentication information are correct.
- The plugin offeres both php-mailer and SMTP mailing options, so try both and see. For php-mailer check the necessary php settings needed as mentioned above.
- As for SMTP issues, you can run a smtp session using telent from the web server and supply the data you are using in the plugin, to see if it works or not. Here is: [How to check an SMTP connection with a manual telnet session.](https://www.port25.com/how-to-check-an-smtp-connection-with-a-manual-telnet-session-2/)

Answer (score 1):

At a guess -- you've configured your SMTP client to require secure connections (hence the STARTTLS request to the server) but the SMTP Server doesn't understand it, so the Client decides it can't connect?

(It's also possible that you're trying to connect to port 25 rather than port 587 which is more often used for TLS SMTP. If you connect to port 25, you have to do the server handshake before issuing the "STARTTLS" command).